# Proper ufw rules for SSL with nginx on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt, ufw

I have a `NodeJs` app served on `nginx` on `ubuntu 14.04`. I am trying secure this site using `ssl` via `letsencrypt`. All the certs including the diffie hellman params are all properly generated. This app is being served on a VPN connection so I got a feeling that the issue is related to firewall and/or network settings.

**nginx**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sample.com;
    # listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name sample.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sample.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sample.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AE$
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

**ufw**

[image]

**NOTES**

Also I noticed a weird behavior of the nodejs app. Whenever I do `sudo ufw enable` (plus the rules) the server will stop working after a few seconds. But after I do `sudo ufw disable` it will work again.